# Optimal strategy in Penney's game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider Penney's game with 3-bit strings. I know that if winning string of first player is given (suppose it's $123$), then the optimal winning string for second player is $not(1),1,2$.

I intuitively understand why it's winning strategy, but I couldn't find mathematical proof why and now I'm seeking for help with it :(

Comment: Conway has a good algorithm for computing the probability in Penney's game, [here](https://penneyante.weebly.com/conways-algorithm.html).

Comment: @lulu thank you for help !